# Is there a vDSP function for 1D vector resampling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, fft, accelerate-framework

I would like be able to use a vector as an envelope to apply fft equalization to rather large chunks of sound, with varying sizes.

To be able to multiply the frequency domain bins by the envelope, the envelope needs to have the same resolution as the fft data, which will vary with the size of the sound chunks.

So, I need a function to resample my envelope vector. Do you know whether vDSP features a function for that purpose? I browsed the reference back and forth, but found nothing. Which doesn't mean there is nothing there - it's easy to miss something while searching the vDSP reference...

It's not that I couldn't implement something myself, but if there was a vDSP function, it would propably be much faster than anything I could possibly come up with. Which is relevant as this project is targeted at iOS devices as well.

And there's no need to reinvent the wheel :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have a 1D array of envelope values which you want to vector multiply with a 1D array of frequency bins. The problem you are trying to solve is to scale the envelope array to the same length as the FFT array. It would be helpful to know how you are generating the envelope array in the first place, can you not simply generate it at the correct length? If so, problem solved :)

If not, then how about using `vDSP_vtabi` to generate the envelope vector from the lookup table of values that you currently have? You can generate the lookup table input vector A using `vDSP_vramp`.

This seems rather complicated and expensive to me though, with a fair amount of buffer mallocing / reallocing. It might be simpler to calculate how many FFT samples should be multiplied by each envelope value, then loop for each envelope sample using `vDSP_vsmul` to multiply chunks of the FFT vector by the envelope value.

Which solution will perform better really depends a lot on the relative sizes of each vector. It would also be helpful to know why the FFT vectors are different sizes, and how you are generating the envelope array in the first place to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: Correct! The fft size is varying because I am fft'ing the whole sound chunk (up to 30 seconds) and not just a fixed amount of samples. The envelope is being calculated based on a template sound, which may also vary in size. I was thinking about something like your second approach too, but I fear there will be artefacts in cases where source an template sound are of similar lenghts. While the envelope is smoothed, it still may have rather steep flanks. Your first approach sounds interesting, but I have to admit I don't fully understand it - can you please explain it a little further? Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm afraid that asks more questions than it answers. Maybe you could take a step back here and tell me what you are actually trying to do? From what I understand, you are calculating the frequency response of a signal and multiplying it by the amplitude envelope of another signal. Why? What do you do then? How are you calculating the FFT of the long signal? Presumably by breaking it into blocks and averaging? Why is the block size not known? Why can the envelope not be the same size as the FFT block size?

Comment: Well I just implemented a resampling function myself. I have to admit I've lazily resorted to linear interpolation, but for my usecase this is ok as the envelope is rather smooth and this way I need to touch each value just once. Turns out it is reasonably fast too, so no urgent need for accelerated functions anymore. I'm still curious though as to why the Accelerate Framework seems to lack such a basic feature, while it takes care of some quite obscure mathematical operations...

Comment: It doesn't, you can use the functions I already mentioned as well as `vDSP_vlint` to "resample" a vector. What is lazy about linear interpolation, how else would you do it?

Comment: @Tark Is there any chance you could elaborate a bit on the methods you describe above for resampling vectors? I need to do something similar (for entirely different reasons) and my own naive implementation is rather slow.

Comment: @WillPragnell If you have a specific question about resampling using vDSP, you should probably ask a separate question with the details, this one is slightly confused with the envelope generation stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go through a different way.

Because your input signal comes from hardware at a fixed sample rate and you exactly 
know the number of envelope values , just make a sample rate conversion using

AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer

It's fast and it take care about filtering and interpolation when resampling.